# How to share code in eclipse projects

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two applications, one for android and one for blackberry and I want to share some common code between the two apps.

I have a folder structure as follows...

```
project
    android
        .metadata (eclipse workspace)
        project
            (android specific project folder layout)
    blackberry
        .metadata (eclipse workspace)
        project
            (blackberry specific project folder layout)
    project.core
        src
            (just source files common to each project above)
```

I just want to reference an external source folder (using relative paths) from the two internal projects. It seems eclipse doesn't like this kind of setup as it prefers source folders to be children of the workspace folder. Due to other reasons I cannot share a common workspace between blackberry and android.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would encourage putting your common code into a separate self contained project. You can then package this into a jar and import it in any of your projects.

Answer (score 1):

I had only two projects with shared code, so I did it this way: the first project has the actual source files, the second project uses a linked folder to point to them.

```
The file system layout:

EclipseWorkspace
   project1
      src
         com
            myApp
               Package
                  myActivity.java
               Shared
                  mySharedClass.java

   project2
      src
         com
            myApp2
               Package
                  myActivity.java


The resulting file layout from the Eclipse Package Explorer view:

project1
   src
      com.myApp.Package
         myActivity.java
      com.myApp.Shared
         mySharedClass.java

project2
   src
      com.myApp2.Package
         myActivity.java
      com.myApp.Shared       NOTE: this folder's icon has a link arrow in it.
         mySharedClass.java
```

To create the linked folder in `project2,` do the following:

1. Navigate to project2's src folder in the Package Explorer and
   right-click it
2. Select New > Folder
3. Immediately click the Advanced button and select *Link to alternate location (Linked Folder)*
4. Click the Variables button
5. Select the WORKSPACE_LOC entry, and click the Extend button
6. Navigate to `project1` and down to its *src / com / myApp / Shared* folder and press OK
7. Finally, set the Folder Name to match the shared package name, e.g. *com.myApp.Shared*, and press Finish